# Prove $a(n)$ tends toward $a(n-1)^\phi $ as $n$ goes to $\infty$

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, asymptotics

The Sequence
$$
a(1)=1,a(2)=1,a(3)=1,a(n+1)=a(n-2) a(n-1)+a(n) a(n-1)+a(n-2) a(n)
$$

I was trying to find a formula for it.

After some failures, I searched it in **OEIS** and found [A074047](http://oeis.org/A074047). It says, $a(n)$ *tends towards* $a(n-1)^\phi$ *and* $1.22376...^{\phi^n}$ *where* $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2=1.6180339887...$

**I am curious that how it could be derived**, and **how does the constant** $1.22376...$ **come ?** . I am having no idea about it now.

Comment: The title needs some editing.

Comment: I edited it. hope that will be better.

Comment: Maybe a part of the solution: note that $a_n$ increases to $\infty$, so $\ln{a_{n+1}}=\ln{a_n}+\ln{a_{n-1}}+o(1)$...

Comment: I think that's not $\ln x$ but maybe $\log_c x$...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Calculating the first few values of the sequence suggests that
$\,a(n) \approx y\,x^{\phi^n}\,$ where $\,x>1.\,$ The appearance
of $\,\phi\,$ comes the recursion equation
$$ a(n+1) = a(n-2) a(n-1)+a(n) a(n-1)+a(n-2) a(n) $$ 
where the dominant terms are $\,a(n+1) = a(n)a(n-1)\,$ which is
a multiplicative form of the Fibonacci recursion equation.
Substituting the Ansatz into the recursion equation 
simplifying and removing common factors gives the equation
$$ 1/y = x^{-\phi^{n+1}} + x^0 + x^{\phi^n-\phi^{n+1}}. $$
Letting $\,n\to\infty\,$ we find that $\,y=1 \,$ and
$\, a(n)^{1/\phi^n} \to x \approx 1.22376155752637.\,$

Comment: how $n\to \infty$ shows $\,y=1 \,$?

Comment: @FFjet Thanks! I fixed a sign error in the $1/y$ equation.

Comment: yeah, and what is the explicit formula for $x$?